# Using fs.readdir returns ENOENT on vps, but not on localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

So I am working on a node js project and I want to load all files from one directory. Everything works on localhost, but when I push it to server, it throws this error:

```
Error: ENOENT, readdir './maps/'
```

The error is here (app.js):

```
        var dir='./maps/';
        fs.readdir(dir,function(err,files){
            if (err) throw err;
            files.forEach(function(file){
                fs.readFile(dir+file,'utf-8',function(err,data){
                    if (err) throw err;                        
                    //code..
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

I triple checked the directory tree on server and it is indeed the same as on localhost, so I have no idea what's happening here.

The directory tree looks like this (both on server and localhost):

```
src
    app.js
    maps
        map1.json
        map2.json
    routes
        index.js
        and so on...
```

The server is running on amazon linux.

Comment: do you run `node app.js` from `$\src\>` locally, and does Amazon actually run `node src\app.js` instead? Because that would cause a dir location mismatch. Simple check: log what `process.cwd()` reports at the start of your app.js, so you know which dir it's actually running out of

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Man, love you, figured it out. Thanks a ton. On local I was starting it directly from from the directory with app.js and on server from the directory above it. Fixed and works perfectly now. Post an answer if you want. :)

Comment: done, with some extra bits on how to force your way to success in terms of which dir is treated as the active directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually run into this when you're starting your server from a different dir locally than remotely.

If you run `node app.js` from `$\src\>` locally, and Amazon actually runs `node src\app.js`, for instance, none of your relative dirs will resolve correctly. A simple way to check is to log what `process.cwd()` reports at the start of your `app.js`, so you know which directory it's actually getting executed in. You can then even -if you want- use `process.chdir()` to navigate the app.js script to make sure all your relative dirs work using something like

```
var path = require("path");
process.chdir(path.dirname(__filename));
```

which will use the location of "this script", which is the global `__filename` in Nodejs (this is an absolute file location btw), find its owning directory (via the `path` module), then changes the active directory to be the same as where the current file is located.